# SSRS lock parameter input

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there any chance I can set a parameter input in SSRS so that the user can only modify but not delete the field?

I'm playing around with a date/time field like this

1/1/2013 12:10:00 PM

I would like to be able to let the user change the date and time but not be able to delete or use the backspace button on this parameter.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Nope. You can use calendar for your parameter values. But user can modify & delete that value. For more you can just set parameter to not null which is by default.

Comment: It's more of not letting the user pass in invalid values and also letting the user not be able to delete the field prevents panic and stuff.

Comment: If the data type is date, then it will accept only date values. But can not lock the field. use null & date data type.

Comment: It's a Datetime field and datetime datatype.

Comment: Is the datepicker/calendar control not cutting it?

Comment: The datepicker does not allow you to select time.

Comment: You would need to use code to do this.  The real question is what exactly are you trying to prevent by doing this?

Comment: Ok, what I need is a way to prevent the user from altering the time semicolon in the parameter input. (Format hh:mm) I would like to prevent the user from erasing the semicolon